# Difference between Role Hierarchy and Territory Management?

Tags: role-hierarchy, territory-management, roles, territory

I have territory already setup with more than 1000 territories. I have seen that roles are not assigned in the org. In roles introduction page, I can see "Territory based Heirarchy" as 1 of the option.

It seems territories allow only few standard objects to control visibility. Do I need to set up roles in order to restrict record visibilty according to territories for custom object?

> This question is about the older **Territory Management** feature, not the newer **Enterprise Territory Management** feature.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The primary difference between the two is the question of "how many"?

In the role hierarchy, you are allowed one role as a user. So if I am in a sales hierarchy where it is only regional (East, Central, West, for instance), no problem.

But what if I also have an industry vertical, and I need to be in *both* East, and the Manufacturing vertical?

This is the intended purpose of territories. In territories, I can be given record access based on *two or more* factors. I can be in one territory that identifies my geographical location, *and* the industry vertical *and* Account size (and as many other factors, potentially as I need).

But I've never implemented it. In fact few have implemented the new Territory Management features as it is a recent addition and replaces the old ugly Territory Management feature. So don't take my word for it, [download the guide.](http://na1.salesforce.com/help/pdfs/en/salesforce_territories_implementation_guide.pdf)

As to why your custom objects don't seem to be playing ball, that is explained in the guide where it states:

> Territory management only affects accounts and the standard objects that have a master-detail relationship to accounts.
>   For example, opportunities are included in territory management but leads are not.

So for record-level permissions (also sometimes referred to as the Sharing Model, record access, record visibility) for custom objects, you must use roles and the role hierarchy.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. I have 1 question. The child objects has lookup relation to Account. So if I change them to master detail, I would be able to control the custom object's visibility through territory management, isn't?

Comment: The way I read that statement, no. I don't consider any standard relationships to be "master-detail", but it says quite clearly that Territory works on standard objects, not custom. But give it a try.

Comment: I will give it a try. Shouldn't the detail side in a MD should inherit the security settings from parent or the Territory Management doesn't work that way? I'm confused

Comment: For Owner, Role Hierarchy, Sharing Rules, Manual Sharing, yes. That is the case. But if a feature doesn't apply to custom objects at all (for example Auto response rules) then it just doesn't apply. In this instance, like I said, I'm not an expert, I know what has been explained to me in the past, and what that doc states.